# Need to write a program that will strip a URL down to just protocol and domain

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a program that can perform some different URL processing tasks.  One of those tasks is to take a URL and remove everything except the protocol and domain.  Below is some sample input and expected output.

Example input:

```
http://www.exp.org/forum/member.php?1-Morrus&language=uk
http://expl.com/forum/member.php/1-%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD?langid=5
```

Expected output:

```
http://www.exp.org/
http://expl.com/
```

Here is a screenshot of the UI I am building:
[image: Screenshot of UI in VS 2012]

Comment: sorry and remove duplicate line thank u

Comment: i want VB aplication

Comment: https://prnt.sc/kjy71m
the screenshot explain what i want

Comment: Please include all necessary information in the question itself, not in dead external links to some site in another language.

Comment: @Pro-TechX0r - the screenshot shows a UI in the VS visual designer but it doesn't show us where you are stuck. Please show us what you have tried - see [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Without further description about the other parts of your program, I have narrowed your question down to just parsing the URL and stripping out the parts you don't want.  The [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class can help make this a little easier. Here is some sample code showing how to start with your input URL and get to your target output.  Another way to do this would be to simply walk the string looking for and counting the number of slashes and just create a substring, but I think this approach is cleaner.

```
Dim uri As New Uri("http://www.exp.org/forum/member.php?1-Morrus&language=uk")
Dim cleaned As String = String.Format("{0}://{1}/", uri.Scheme, uri.Host)
```